# HTML / PHP : Convert string of text to table

Tags: php, html, html-table, import-from-csv

On my intranet, me and my users are storing rather long strings of text into database.

These strings of text often come from `Excel` or `CSV` files.
At the moment, they are displayed as plain text.

What I'd like is these strings of texts to be automatically processed and transformed into HTML tables when some separators are detected in their body (such as comas or tabs).

Here is a example of the kind of "script" I need :[csv-convert-table](http://www.textfixer.com/html/csv-convert-table.php)

Can this be achieved only with PHP without requiring any additional module?

Comment: Yes it can.... though your description of "long strings of text" is pretty meaningless.... it takes about 20 lines of code to open/load a csv file and display it as an html table.... but "without any additional module" probably means that it's going to take you a long time to write it for Excel files, unless you're prepared to use external libraries

Comment: @MarkBaker I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough... I do not want to import actual CSV or XLS file. What I meant is that we are used to copy informations from such files, and then simply paste them as plain text in our database. This is that plain text including separators (as I said, comas or tabs) which I need to convert to table in my code :)

Comment: Well it probably takes about 20 lines of code to read a CSV string from your database, use str_getcsv() to parse it to an array, and then display it as html.... it's your description of storing Excel that's pretty weird.... are you storing the entire binary of a file in your database?

Comment: @MarkBaker Nope, we only store small amount of text (maximum 10 lines). Each line looks something like : "column1, column2, column3"... Actually, just forget about Excel or CSV, this is not what is important in my description.

Answer (score 2):

Code for converting CSV file to HTML table directly

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("tn-tiger-july-1.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $htmlval = "<table class='table-div' align='center' border='1' cellpadding='3' cellspacing='0'>";
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $htmlval = $htmlval."<tr>";
        $num = count($data);        
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            if($data[$c] != "" || trim($data[$c]) != " "){
                $htmlval = $htmlval. "<td class='cols' align='center'>".$data[$c]."</td>";
            }else{
                $htmlval = $htmlval. "<td class='cols'>&nbsp;</td>";
            }
        }
        $htmlval = $htmlval."</tr>";
    }
    $htmlval = $htmlval."</table>";
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

In the above code variable `$htmlval` will contain data from CSV into HTML table format.
Hope this will help you :)